# Is it possible to change html form value with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have html table with some rows. When i select one of these rows, i want to modify that row. I direct to other page like this: 
window.location.href = `/taxes/addTax/id=${tableSeven.row(this).data()[0]}`;
But I want to set default value, with the one that I had. I am using node.js for backend by the way. Is possible to do this either with Js or NodeJs?

Comment: You can read the query string with `location.search` - is that what you mean?

Comment: In your case, you could read your `id` as: `const id = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('id')`, but your URL looks malformed. It should either be `?id=value` or `/id/value`.